# Why is momentum conserved when internal force is 0 of an isolated system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws

Force is dp/dt, integral of which is momentum.

Velocity is dx/dt, integral of which is displacement.

If velocity is 0, displacement is always 0.

Why is momentum not 0, when force is 0?

Why is momentum only conserved, not necessarily 0, while the internal force is 0 in an isolated system?

Comment: The momentum of an isolated system can only be **changed** by the application of **external** forces.

Comment: In this question, I am assuming no external force only internal forces. I know that total internal forces are zero. But, why momentum is not necessarily 0, but constant?
Why momentum is not 0, since force is zero?

Comment: Zero force implies constant not necessarily zero momentum.

Comment: Why is that?
But, in the case of velocity and displacement, if velocity o, displacement is also 0.

Comment: Zero velocity only means constant diaplacement, it need not be zero

Comment: If the object does not move then both displacement and velocity is 0.

Comment: Why can there be displacement if there is 0 meter moved per second?

Comment: Again if the velocity is zero then the **change** in displacement is zero.

Comment: "If velocity is 0, displacement is always 0." This is incorrect. Counter example: my dog is at rest at a few meters displacement .

Comment: "If velocity is 0, displacement is always 0." This is not true. Eg :- If you throw a ball upwards in the sky, then at the highest point its velocity will be zero but its displacement would not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to calculate the variation of the linear momentum $p$ of a body of fixed mass you'll find that the variation is equal to $\Delta p=F_{tot}=F_{int}+F_{ext}$. This is because of the second law of Newton. The third law ensure that $F_{int}=0$ and then you can conclude that if $F_{ext}=0$ then $\Delta p=0$.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately in the comments, it is said that the statement of "if the velocity is zero, the displacement is zero" is incorrect. But, it is indeed correct. The displacement is the change in position, i.e. $\Delta x$, and it is zero if $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$. So, you are right here.

But it is the comparison between the **displacement** and the **momentum** that is incorrect in your question. Because momentum, $p$, should be compared to the position, $x$, not the displacement (change in position), $\Delta x$. The counterpart of the displacement in this context would be impulse, $\Delta p$, i.e., the change in momentum.

So, everything is actually consistent:

If the **velocity** is zero, i.e. $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$, then the **displacement** is zero as well, $\Delta x =0$, and the position is constant (conserved).

Likewise, if the **force** is zero, i.e. $\frac{dp}{dt}=0$, then **impulse** is zero as well, $\Delta p =0$, and the momentum is constant (conserved).

Comment: No the statement is correct $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ implies that displacement is constant as per the rules of calculus, or if you'd like a non calculus example $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = 0 \Rightarrow \Delta x = 0 \Rightarrow x_f - x_0 = 0 \Rightarrow x_f = x_0$, where you can see that the final and initial displacement need not be zero to satisfy the requirements

Comment: @TheMathemagician Displacement is defined as $\Delta x = x(t) - x (t_i)$ where i indicates "initial". So, If you solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ by integrating for t, then you would obtain a solution like $x(t) - x(t_i)=0$ which means $\Delta x =0$. So, the displacement is indeed zero, as Triatticus said.